# Innodb statistics

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, innodb, munin

We're running `InnoDB` as a MySQL engine and using phpMyadmin to administer our database. Under `Status` → `Query statistics`, phpMyadmin gives us the following:

[image: phpMyAdmin Screenshot]

We would like to know where these figures come from because we would like to create a `Munin` graph showing the evolution of these statistics over time.

When we run the `SHOW STATUS;` query here is what we get:

```
Innodb_rows_deleted 247555
Innodb_rows_inserted    822911
Innodb_rows_read    694934413
Innodb_rows_updated 15048
```

As you can see there is a substantial difference although both were taking almost at the same time.

**Q: Do you know where `phpMyadmin` gets its values from?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `RolandoMySQLDBA` mentioned, the first thing to bear in mind is the difference between `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW STATUS` ([see documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html)). Regarding the values displayed by `phpMyadmin`, they are obtained from the [`Com_*` variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Com_xxx) as confirmed by source code:

**server_status.php**

```
    $sql = "SELECT concat('Com_', variable_name), variable_value
    FROM data_dictionary.GLOBAL_STATEMENTS
    [...]

    // For the percentage column, use Questions - Connections, because
    // the number of connections is not an item of the Query types
    // but is included in Questions. Then the total of the percentages is 100.
    $name = str_replace(array('Com_', '_'), array('', ' '), $name);
```

After comparison, it appears that `phpMyAdmin` is displaying the correct values (i.e. matching what `MySQL` is reporting).

Answer (score 3):

Please note the MySQL Documentation on [**SHOW STATUS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-status.html)

Looking at the numbers, phpmyadmin must be using `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` because it bring up statistics from the time MySQL was started up.

When you use `SHOW STATUS;`, that brings back session-level statistics which go wawy when the DB Connections terminates.

Comment: +1, great info on `SHOW GLOBAL` vs `SHOW`.

Comment: +1 indeed on `SHOW GLOBAL` vs `SHOW`

Answer (score -1):

The best data is obtained by asking MySQL itself. It's also far easier to implement that trying to interface with phpMyAdmin. How phpMyAdmin gets its numbers is anyone's guess but I wouldn't trust them.

Comment: I agree, I guess I could have a look at the source code of `phpMyAdmin` to find out, but in the end I'm only interested into what `MySQL` is actually reporting`. Are there any other `InnoDB`-related variables than the 4 aforementioned I should be paying attention to you think?

Comment: @user64204, I suggest you have a look at some of the MySQL "tuning" scripts and use them to help you determine what might be most relevant in your particular situation. You might also gain something from what they can tell you about your system.

Comment: C'mon, phpMyAdmin gets its numbers from internal MySQL functions just like everything else does. It's just a web client for MySQL.

Comment: @ceejayoz, and yet it pretty consistently gets it wrong.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers For example...?

Comment: @ceejayoz, for example this very question.

Comment: It's reporting perfectly valid data in this question. See @RolandoMySQLDBA's answer. phpMyAdmin's numbers are the **right** numbers here.

Comment: Indeed, `phpMyAdmin` is displaying the correct numbers, I was just looking at the wrong variables from the wrong command, my bad.